# I'm very new to programming. Is this acceptable?

Tags: python, function

Is it acceptable to use functions like this?  I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.  Is this the correct way to pass values into an array?

```
def calculateTuitionIncrease(cost, increase, years):  
    counter = 1  
    costsPerYear = []  
    while counter <= years:  
        cost = (cost)+(cost*increase)  
        costsPerYear.append(cost)   
        counter = counter + 1  
    return costsPerYear

def calculateTotalCost(terms,tuition,creditHours,books,roomAndBoard,scholarships):  
    totalBookCost = (books*terms)  
    totalRoomAndBoard =(roomAndBoard*terms)  
    totalCost = (totalBookCost+tuition+totalRoomAndBoard)-(scholarships)  
    return totalCost
```

Is it okay to use a function to let the user exit the program or is there a better way to do it?

```
def exitProgram():  
    quitProgram = str(raw_input("Would you like to exit the program (y,n)"))  
    while quitProgram != "y" and quitProgram != "n":  
        quitProgram = str(raw_input("Type 'y' if you would like to exit the program and 'n' if you would like to run it again."))  
    return quitProgram


def main():
    endProgram = "n"
    while endProgram == "n":

        #Variable declaration/initialization
        years = 0
        terms = 0
        numberOfSchools = 0

        tuitionCost1 = 0
        tuitionCost2 = 0
        tuitionCost3 = 0
        tuitionCost = 0

        bookCost = 0
        roomAndBoard = 0
        scholarships = 0

        tuitionIncrease = 0
        adjustedTuitions = 0
        sumOfTuitionCosts = 0
        averageTuitionCost = 0
        totalTuitionCost = 0

        creditHours = 0
        overallCost = 0

        #User inputs
        years = int(input("Will you be going to school for 2, 4 or 6 years?"))

        while years != 2 and years != 4 and years !=6: #Input validation for years.
            years = int(input("Please try again. Do you plan on going to school for 2, 4 or 6 years?"))

        #If-statements for if the user will be attending multiple schools.
        if years == 4 or years == 6:
            numberOfSchools = int(input("How many schools do you plan on attending during this time?"))

        if numberOfSchools == 2:
            tuitionCost1 = int(input("How much will you be paying per credit hour at the first school you'll be attending?"))
            tuitionCost2 = int(input("How much will you be paying per credit hour at the second school you'll be attending?"))
            tuitionCost = (tuitionCost1+tuitionCost2)/(2) #Finds average tuition between schools & assigns it to a variable

        elif numberOfSchools == 3:
            tuitionCost1 = int(input("How much will you be paying per credit hour at the first school you'll be attending?"))
            tuitionCost2 = int(input("How much will you be paying per credit hour at the second school you'll be attending?"))
            tuitionCost3 = int(input("How much will you be paying per credit hour at the third school you'll be attending?"))
            tuitionCost = (tuitionCost1+tuitionCost2+tuitionCost3)/(3) #Finds average tuition cost between schools & assigns it to a variable

        else:
            tuitionCost = int(input("Please enter how much you will be paying per credit hour."))

        terms = (years*2)

        #User inputs
        tuitionIncrease = float(input("Please enter the projected tuition increase per year in percentage form (ex. if increase is 7% enter .07)."))
        creditHours = int(input("On average, how many credit hours will you be receiving per term?"))
        roomAndBoard = int(input("Please enter what your price of room and board will be per term."))
        bookCost = int(input("Please enter what your average book cost will be per term."))
        scholarships = int(input("Please enter the total amount you will be recieving from grants and scholarships."))

        #Calls function that calculates tuition increase per year
        adjustedTuitions = calculateTuitionIncrease(tuitionCost, tuitionIncrease, years)

        sumOfTuitionCosts = sum(adjustedTuitions)
        averageTuitionCost = (sumOfTuitionCosts/years) #Average cost of tuition between all schools including the projected tuition increase.
        totalTuitionCost = (averageTuitionCost* creditHours)*(terms) #Calculates total cost of JUST tuition.

        #Calls function that calculates the total cost of all expenses.
        overallCost = calculateTotalCost(terms,totalTuitionCost,creditHours,bookCost,roomAndBoard,scholarships)


        if numberOfSchools ==2 or numberOfSchools ==3:  #Average tuition rate is only displayed if the user is attending more than 1 college.
            print("The average tuition cost per credit hour between the schools you'll be attending, including the projected tuition increase is", round(averageTuitionCost, 2))

        print ("The total estimated cost for your tuition alone is",round(totalTuitionCost, 2)) #total cost of TUITION ONLY.
        print ("Your total estimated college cost with all expenses is", round(overallCost, 2)) #cost for ALL expenses.

        endProgram = exitProgram()#Calls function that lets user choose to end program

main()
```

Comment: Can't get what you really mean?

Comment: Is creating a function the best way to allow the user to exit the program or should I not create a function and keep all of that code inside of the main module?

Comment: Use a module. That will clearify your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have two unrelated questions here.

The first is whether your `calculateTutitionIncrease` function does the right thing to create an list of cost values over time.

It is not bad, exactly, but it could be better. To start with, you could use a `for` loop over a `range`, rather than a `while` loop testing an integer that you manually increment. An even more "Pythonic" style of code is to use a list comprehension when you want to create a list of items from some other sequence (like the range of year numbers). This requires a slightly different mathematical calculation in this case, but the results should be the same:

```
costs_per_year = [cost * (1+increase)**year for year in range(1, years+1)]
```

Your second question seems to be about whether you should keep your code for asking if the user wants to quit in a separate function. This is fairly subjective, so there really isn't a single right answer. I think there are two good reasons that you might want to have it in its own function.

First, it can help make your other code simpler, especially if most of the other work is also separated out into functions:

```
def main():
    while True:
        input_data = get_input()
        results = calculate_results(input_data)
        display_results(results)
        if ask_to_exit():
            break
```

You don't see much benefit to this currently, because your `main` function is already quite long and complicated.

The second reason is if you might want to call it from multiple different places in your other code. For instance, if you had two different loops, it might make sense to use the same function to ask the user if they were done in each of them. This doesn't currently apply to your code though, since you only call your `exitProgram` function in exactly one place.

So, in the end, neither of the reasons speak strongly to your situation. That doesn't necessarily mean that you should stick the contents of `exitProgram` back into `main` though. If you think you might change the other code (for instance, by factoring out the other steps you go through in `main` into functions of their own), it might make sense to keep `exitProgram` as a separate function too.

A few further suggestions:

Pick a different name for your `exitProgram` function, if you choose to keep it. Functions are usually given names that are verbs describing what they do. Your `exitProgram` function is misleading though, since it doesn't actually cause the program to exit (it just returns what the users desire is, regarding exiting). I'd suggest that you make it return a `bool` value too, rather than a `y` or `n` string that the caller will need to test against.

Also, Python code convention is for functions and variables to be named in `lower_case_with_underscores` format, rather than `camelCase` like you are currently using. [See PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) for more Python style suggestions.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a ton. I'm just starting Python so I've got a lot to learn. And how would I go about making my `exitProgram` function return a `bool` value instead of a `y` or `n` string?

Comment: @slobiwan: I'd probably do `return quitProgram == "y"`, rather than just `return quitProgram`.